# DLL missing in Mono/MonoGame project in Xamarin

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, xamarin

I just started using MonoGame to make a game in Xamarin Studio. However, I'm also using Mono.Cairo to render the graphics.

Everything works fine on my PC, the code compiles and runs and there's no problem. When I gave the game to my friend, it didn't work, saying that Mono.Cairo.dll was missing.

So I tried including Mono.Cairo.dll with the game. Apparently there's no way to do that from within Xamarin Studio, other than just finding the file in your Mono folder and copying it to the output bin folder every time you want to distribute it, but that's okay, no big deal.

Then my friend saw that libcairo-2.dll was missing. Understandable, as his computer doesn't have GTK+ installed on it, and Mono.Cairo.dll is just the wrapper. However, after downloading libcairo-2.dll from the GTK+ website and including it with the game, he gets the same error message, saying that libcairo-2.dll is missing, even though it's right there in the folder alongside Mono.Cairo.dll and the game executable.

Am I missing something super obvious, or is there now no way to distribute this game other than to require GTK+ be downloaded and installed? Also, is there really no way to set Xamarin Studio to automatically include these needed DLLs in the output folders?

The error message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'libcairo-2 .dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80070 07E) at
>   Cairo.NativeMethods.cairo_image_surface_create(Format format, Int32
>   width, Int32 height) at Cairo.ImageSurface..ctor(Format format, Int32
>   width, Int32 height) at VGame.Renderer.Resize(Int32 width, Int32
>   height) at VGame.VectorGameSession..ctor() at Arena.Program.Main()

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a way to tell Xamarin to include the DLLs in the output folders.

In your solution, select your project, and then open/expand the `References` folder.

To include a local copy of a .dll-file in your binary output folder, you **right click it** in the references folder **and check *local copy***.

**Edit:**
If you manually want to include a .dll-file, right click the references folder, click `Edit References`, choose `.Net-Assembly` and navigate to your .dll-file.